# Selecting multiple values in a filter

Tags: excel-2010

I have thousand of dates in a column. I would like to select multiple dates in the column, how can this be done?

```
 Date
 01/01/2017
 05/01/2017
 06/01/2017
 08/01/2017
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to trim the empty spaces in the column, then order by the date. From there, select from the drop down filter.